# is there a way to edit primeng PickList actions?

Tags: angular, primeng, picklist

I'm using this module in my project https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/picklist but I need to change what happens when I double tab an item in the list. right now double tabbing an item moves it from one list to the other but I need to change that to calling a method I made and not moving the item to the second list. is there a way to do this?

```
<p-pickList (onMoveToTarget)="refresh($event);" [source]="availableTransformers" [target]="selectedTransformers" sourceHeader="Available" targetHeader="Selected" [responsive]="true" filterBy="type" 
    dragdrop="true" dragdropScope="transformers" sourceFilterPlaceholder="Search by name" targetFilterPlaceholder="Search by name" [sourceStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" [targetStyle]="{'height':'300px'}">
<ng-template let-transformer pTemplate="item">
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div style="font-size:14px;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{transformer.type}}</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
</p-pickList>
```

Comment: Can you share the code which you are following?

Comment: I edited the post and added the angular html code

Comment: p-pickList is missing end tag

Comment: you're right I fixed that

Comment: UPDATE
I found out that I can use (dblclick) action to call any method I want. the only problem I have now is stopping the item from moving to the second list when double clicking